# How to generate all possible routes between two points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, pgrouting, routing, network-analyst

I have a network dataset in ArcGIS and I need to generate all possible (not only the shortest one) routes between two given points (A, B).

Is it possible to do it with the Network Analyst?

Or with any other software? e.g. pgrouting?

Comment: In general, no, because there are infinitely many routes.  (Just keep bouncing back and forth along one segment for a while before continuing, or follow a loop multiple times.) This shows that you need to be more specific about what you might mean by "all" routes. Note, too, that many routes differ almost inconsequentially: one can take a minor detour off of and then back on to the best route (often in many different ways) to get an almost-best route.

Answer (score 6):

The question has been asked before on Stack Overflow:

- [Find all paths between two graph nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535819/find-all-paths-between-two-graph-nodes); and
- [Graph Algorithm To Find All Connections Between Two Arbitrary Vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306/graph-algorithm-to-find-all-connections-between-two-arbitrary-vertices)